# user.name returns :name key - Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book.Running user.name returns the :name key in my rails console instead of the "MyName" value.The console commands are;

```
require user.rb 
 => true 
user = User.new(:name =>"Myname", :email=> "email@example.com")
user.name   
=>[:name]
user.email
=>[:email]
```

As mentioned, running user.name or user.email returns [:name] and [:email] respectively.What could be the problem?

```
class User    
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  def initialize (attributes = {})
    @name = [:name]
    @email = [:email]
  end

  def formatted_email
    "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have:

```
@name = attributes[:name]
@email = attributes[:email]
```

in your `User#initialize` method.